# JavaPlot graph only uses half of canvas

Tags: java, gnuplot, javaplot

I'm trying to use JavaPlot to automatically graph some data. Everything about the graph is being generated fine, but it is only using half the canvas. I can adjust the canvas size, and the graph will adjust accordingly, always using half the canvas. I can't seem to find anything that would fix this.

```
JavaPlot jPlot = new JavaPlot();
String norm = normalized ? "Normalized" : "Absolute";
PostscriptTerminal epsf = new PostscriptTerminal(String.format("output/graphs/%s_%s_%s.pdf", dataset.toString(), distribution.getName(), norm));
jPlot.setTerminal(epsf);
jPlot.setTitle(String.format("%s %s %s", dataset.toString(),
distribution.getName(), norm));
jPlot.getAxis("x").setLabel("Budget");
jPlot.getAxis("y").setLabel((norm) + " Performance");
jPlot.setKey(JavaPlot.Key.TOP_LEFT);

/* Adding data code not shown */

jPlot.newGraph();
jPlot.plot();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the `jPlot.newGraph()` call, which I thought was necessary to write the data to the graph, actually just makes a new, blank graph next to my original. Removing that fixed the problem.